# TypeScript: How to define different types of array elements based on a given type definition?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, type-conversion, key

Lately I was trying to do some typescript magic and got stuck on casting.

Let's say I have something like this:

```js
type Test = {
    v1: string
    v2: { v3: string }
    v4: [
        { v5: string },
        { v6: string }
    ]
}

type Help1 = { [k: string]: string }
type Help2 = { [k: string]: string | Help2 | Array<Help1> }

type T1<T = string> = [name: T, str: string]
type T2<T extends Help2 = any, K extends keyof T = any> = [name: K, value: T[K]]
type T3<T extends Array<Help1> = any, I extends keyof T = any> = [name: keyof T[I], value: string][]

type Combined<T extends Help2 = any, K extends keyof T = string> = Array<
    T[K] extends Array<Help1> ? T3<T[K]>
    : T[K] extends Help1 ? T2<T[K]>
    : T[K] extends string ? T1<K>
    : never
>

// code below throws an error
const test: Combined<Test> = [
    ['v1', 'test-string'],
    ['v2', [
        ['v3', 'test-string']
    ]],
    ['v4', [
        [
            ['v5', 'test-string'],
            ['v6', 'test-string']
        ],
        [
            ['v5', 'test-string2'],
            ['v6', 'test-string2']
        ]
    ]]
]
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8BQVtQG4EYAuKRAJwEsA7Acyx1wCZi08BmYsq6qAXzu1wAWYgG1+ObC1wBWDsAo1eAGnESpANjkLufCQF0MfDKEhQAEhAA2YfCnRQRAay1c9LxXxPQL1hnZZO7tRuJPJcUAA+5lZgflEAgqSkAIYgADw+NgB8vBjG4NAw+Gkwdpw0OagilMkAthDEMEqhpEEGXrAMJVAQAB7AEJQAJvDRvnbJlCDNANI9-YMjUI4QIAD2AGawE1OVDjX1xDPNuMmWAK4NsCIzeu0FsKzdfQPDo4kp6Zn4e5PTUABJeavJYrdZbUqoP57ap1K5gzbXAF6E5nS5tEQGfKmADCa1qACMqBAhs8Fm8xrEdv85i9FqMERCymEKnYPqk0uIYDc9MD6VB2V8Yj8oAB+R4lHlZcSNHl8infMWdSW3aUSWW3eVLcrccVFNIzNU4YiUCC4CCkDDSjAAYzWlEQUAGiGIeMJxNJcEQMPEIgA5AQ-c0-c7gABaHV+lG+gMMIMOVQ4f24VjxkMIcORgz6aMSZOCeNiCR5xPFhwB6Rp0MRlnUKMqMtl5PqKsZmvaKOlqC5xtFxt5iutxDtrhxnv97DNoeZ2tjrvZnB3DB6IA)

What I want to achieve is to be able to determine name and value pairs of Combined type by passing another type ( Test in the example ), so that the `const test` is ok.

Comment: Your code has/had a few syntax errors. I suggested an [edit], but you should verify that I interpreted what you were trying to say correctly. I recommend plugging your code into a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) for others to view with type-checking enabled, esp. since it looks like your definition of `Combined` is erroneous to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I did as You said.